# SELECT from table with WHERE and selecting from table with results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called clients. There's a parent child relationship in the table. Here's what it looks like:

```
clientID     |     code    |    cName    |   sub
------------      ------        -----       -----
1                  STK        Stackover       0    <---- parent
2                  GOGL        Google         0    <---- parent
3                  MSFT       Microsoft       1    <-- child of stackover
```

What I'm trying to do is a LIKE search, but I want my like search to pull up parents and children vise/versa. So in this example, if I search for "stk" OR "Stackover", not only do I get Stackover, but also Microsoft. If I search for Microsoft, I get microsoft and stackover. How do i pull this off? This is my existing query:

```
SELECT  code, cName 
FROM    clients 
WHERE   cName LIKE '%Stack%' 
OR      code LIKE '%Stack%' 
AND     active='True' 
ORDER BY cName
```

This would only return the stack.

Comment: CommonTableExpression if you got multiple levels, just an union if you got just one level above or below. Please be specific on your question and also try to search more, for sure there's already some usefull answer in SO

Comment: I don't see anything in your data that establishes a parent-child relationship. How can I tell from the data that `Microsoft` is a child of `Stackover`?

Comment: the sub=clientID. Microsoft sub is 1 which tells it that it's parent is clientID=1 = Stackover

Comment: @sstan there is sub field, which is clientId

Comment: You should add another table to link the relationships otherwise what's the point of using a relational database?

Comment: @Damien: Ah, sorry about that.  It looked like a boolean field to me because of the zeroes.

Comment: I don't think this is going to be a union, it's going to have to be a join or inner select. Either way, at least IMHO I would think it would be good to get your primary results first, then iterate through and get the children to each parent. Doing it that way, you can continue to iterate through actually creating deeper and deeper trees..again IMHO

Comment: You do know AND is processed before OR?

Comment: @Dane A relation in the table is relational and is the proper design here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE
  (
    clientID INT ,
    code VARCHAR(10) ,
    cName VARCHAR(10) ,
    sub INT
  );

INSERT  @myTable ( [clientID], [code], [cName], [sub] )
VALUES  ( 1, 'STK', 'StackOver', 0 ),
        ( 2, 'GOGL', 'Google', 0 ),
        ( 3, 'MSFT', 'Microsoft', 1 );


WITH  t ( clientId, code, cname, rootId )
        AS (
             SELECT clientID, code, cName, clientID AS rootId
             FROM   @myTable AS [mt]
             WHERE  [sub] = 0
             UNION ALL
             SELECT mt.clientID, mt.code, mt.cName, t.[rootId]
             FROM   @myTable AS [mt]
             INNER JOIN t ON t.clientId = mt.[sub]
           ),
      roots
        AS (
             SELECT rootId
             FROM   t
             WHERE  cname LIKE '%Stack%' OR
                    code LIKE '%Stack%'
           )
  SELECT  [t].[code], [t].[cname]
  FROM    t
  INNER JOIN roots rt ON [rt].[rootId] = [t].[rootId];
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near ','

Comment: that was on the insert so not important. Can you explain that sql to me for the searching/selecting?

Comment: This worked out way better than I actually even wanted. It pulled up all related records. Parent and all children. Nice! Anyway you can break this down for me. I would love to know where do you even start on a query like this. What's all that AS stuff? Thanks a bunch man!!!!

Comment: Declare myTable ..., insert into myTable part is for constructing a sample table. with t (,,,) as ( select ... ) is referred to as a Common Table Expression (CTE). A CTE, with union all, like the above is used to create hierarchical relations in tables that has a reference to themselves like yours.  In that first CTE "select clientId, code ..., clientId as RootID from myTable" part is the anchor, second part of the CTE creates the hierarchy. Then we do a second CTE to get rootIds and name ir roots. We can use that t and roots virtual in memory tables in the final select.   HTH.

Comment: Mind Blown! Still having a rough time grasping what's going on, but thanks for showing me how to do it. You learn something new everyday!

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT c1.clientid,c1.code, c1.cName,c1.sub FROM clients c1
    WHERE c1.cName LIKE '%Stack%' OR c1.code LIKE '%Stack%'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c2.clientid,c2.code, c2.cName,c2.sub FROM clients c1 
        LEFT JOIN clients c2 ON c2.sub = c1.clientid
    WHERE c1.cName LIKE '%Stack%' OR c1.code LIKE '%Stack%'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT c2.clientid,c2.code, c2.cName,c2.sub FROM clients c1
        LEFT JOIN clients c2
    ON c1.sub = c2.clientid
    WHERE c1.cName LIKE '%Stack%' OR c1.code LIKE '%Stack%'
) a
WHERE a.clientid IS NOT null
```

Comment: This assumes that there would only one level. Add another level and it wouldn't work IMHO.

Comment: @CetinBasoz do you mean to say 3 referecence 1 and 1 might reference 2, can you think twice?

Comment: Suppose there is another entry with (ClientId, Code, Cname, sub) - (4, 'CODE', 'SAMPLE', 3) which is a child of Microsoft. It wouldn't be included, would it? And BTW there is no Active field in sample.

Comment: @CetinBasoz yes its possible but think 3 reference 1 and 1 reference 2 and 2 reference 3 so you end up having a loops or more checks? so generally these tables are kept single depth and Active field is mentioned on his working query

Comment: No it doesn't need to be. Check the code in my answer. It allows you to have N depth + you need to write the where part once (which would prevent redundancy).

Comment: @CetinBasoz fine but how do we accurate N depth for redundancy?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are asking. Try the code I gave, you write where part once, not N times for N depth.

Comment: @brykneval that was someone else asking questions. I just ran a test with the code and it looked promising at first. Searching Stack returned stack and microsoft. The problem is if i search microsoft, stack doesn't come up. Any ideas?

Comment: @Damien you said you need that way in question, and that answer is right according to ur question? so now you need other ways?

Comment: I'm sorry, but i always needed it both ways. Your solution comes close. Here's what i wrote in the last paragraph up top: 'if i search for "stk" OR "Stackover", not only do i get Stackover, but also Microsoft. If i search for Microsoft, I get microsoft and stackover'. Thanks!!

Comment: @Damien If i search for Microsoft, I get microsoft and stackover, this sentence means you got this solved :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90353/discussion-between-brykneval-and-damien).